# Symlinks on /dev/ttyUSB* via udev

Tags: debian, udev

So I built a nice little GSM-Gateway with a PC-Engines ALIX.2D13, a Huawei E220 umts modem, Debian Wheezy and gammu-smsd.
I need a fixed device name für gammu-smsd to survive reboots. I tried to make following udev rules, but i can't find out why it doesn't work.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1003", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00", SYMLINK+="gsm0"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1003", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="01", SYMLINK+="gsm1"
```

My udevadm output is the following:

```
root@ko-smsgw-01:~# udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.4/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.4/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="option1"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.4/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="2-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="option"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{interface}=="Data Interface"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.4/usb2/2-1':
    KERNELS=="2-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 3"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1126"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="1003"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="7"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="HUAWEI Technologies"
    ATTRS{product}=="HUAWEI Mobile"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.4/usb2':
    KERNELS=="usb2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="  0mA"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="180"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0302"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.2.0-4-486 ohci_hcd"
    ATTRS{product}=="OHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:0f.4"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.4':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:0f.4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ohci_hcd"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1022"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x2094"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1022"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x2094"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0310"
    ATTRS{irq}=="12"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: It might be useful to see the `udevadm` output for /dev/ttyUSB1 as well (or whatever your second interface was assigned).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#udevinfo

> while it is legal to combine the attributes from the device in question and a single parent device, you cannot mix-and-match attributes from multiple parent devices - your rule will not work

Based from your example, you're referencing 2 parent devices in each rule which is wrong.

1. ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
2. ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1003"