# Why isn't the USB device being enumerated correctly after reset?

Tags: drivers, usb, embedded

I have an embedded Linux device connected to a Sierra Wireless WP7610. The WP7610 has three USB serial ports which are enumerated as 0, 1 and 2. This is fine until the WP7610 resets, for instance by sending it an AT+RESET command. When it reappears the USB ports are enumerated as 1, 2 and 3. My assumption is that /dev/ttyUSB0 is being held by something but I can't figure out what.

Before the reset the device appears as:

```
# ls -al /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw----    1 root     root      188,   0 Feb 15 13:05 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw----    1 root     root      188,   1 Feb 15 13:05 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw-rw----    1 root     root      188,   2 Feb 15 13:05 /dev/ttyUSB2

# cat /proc/devices | grep -i “ttyUSB”
188 ttyUSB

# cat /proc/tty/driver/usbserial
usbserinfo:1.0 driver:2.0
0: module:GobiSerial name:"GobiSerial" vendor:1199 product:68c0 num_ports:1 port:0 path:usb-AmbUSB-1
1: module:GobiSerial name:"GobiSerial" vendor:1199 product:68c0 num_ports:1 port:0 path:usb-AmbUSB-1
2: module:GobiSerial name:"GobiSerial" vendor:1199 product:68c0 num_ports:1 port:0 path:usb-AmbUSB-1

# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by    Tainted: G  
GobiNet               460334  0 
GobiSerial             18134  3 
usbserial              41154  7 GobiSerial
rndis_host              9899  0 
cdc_ether               9675  1 rndis_host
usbnet                 34161  3 GobiNet,rndis_host,cdc_ether
mii                     4994  1 usbnet
cdc_acm                24834  0 
ehci_ambarella          3615  0 
ehci_hcd               77691  1 ehci_ambarella
usbcore               244473  9 GobiNet,GobiSerial,usbserial,rndis_host,cdc_ether,usbnet,cdc_acm,ehci_ambarella,ehci_hcd
cfg80211              337122  0 
rfkill                 13990  1 cfg80211

# cat /proc/tty/drivers
/dev/tty             /dev/tty        5       0 system:/dev/tty
/dev/console         /dev/console    5       1 system:console
/dev/ptmx            /dev/ptmx       5       2 system
/dev/vc/0            /dev/vc/0       4       0 system:vtmaster
usbserial            /dev/ttyUSB   188 0-511 serial
acm                  /dev/ttyACM   166 0-255 serial
ambarella-uart       /dev/ttyS       4 64-66 serial
pty_slave            /dev/pts      136 0-1048575 pty:slave
pty_master           /dev/ptm      128 0-1048575 pty:master
unknown              /dev/tty        4 1-63 console
```

After reset:

```
# ls -al /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw----    1 root     root      188,   1 Feb 19 14:55 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw-rw----    1 root     root      188,   2 Feb 19 14:55 /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-rw----    1 root     root      188,   3 Feb 19 14:55 /dev/ttyUSB3

# cat /proc/tty/drivers
/dev/tty             /dev/tty        5       0 system:/dev/tty
/dev/console         /dev/console    5       1 system:console
/dev/ptmx            /dev/ptmx       5       2 system
/dev/vc/0            /dev/vc/0       4       0 system:vtmaster
usbserial            /dev/ttyUSB   188 0-511 serial
acm                  /dev/ttyACM   166 0-255 serial
ambarella-uart       /dev/ttyS       4 64-66 serial
pty_slave            /dev/pts      136 0-1048575 pty:slave
pty_master           /dev/ptm      128 0-1048575 pty:master
unknown              /dev/tty        4 1-63 console

# cat /proc/tty/driver/usbserial
usbserinfo:1.0 driver:2.0
1: module:GobiSerial name:"GobiSerial" vendor:1199 product:68c0 num_ports:1 port:0 path:usb-AmbUSB-1
2: module:GobiSerial name:"GobiSerial" vendor:1199 product:68c0 num_ports:1 port:0 path:usb-AmbUSB-1
3: module:GobiSerial name:"GobiSerial" vendor:1199 product:68c0 num_ports:1 port:0 path:usb-AmbUSB-1
```

I either want to stop this happening or be able to fix it. I tried deleting the new USB ports then redefining them:

```
rm /dev/ttyUSB1
rm /dev/ttyUSB2
rm /dev/ttyUSB3
mknod /dev/ttyUSB0 c 188 0
mknod /dev/ttyUSB1 c 188 1
mknod /dev/ttyUSB2 c 188 2
```

But that doesn't change `cat /proc/tty/driver/usbserial`. I tried unloading the drivers:

```
rmmod /lib/modules/GobiSerial.ko
modprobe -r usbserial
```

But that fails with the error:

```
modprobe: can't unload module 'usbserial': Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I tried replacing GobiSerial with qcserial but I'm seeing the same problem:

```
cat /proc/tty/driver/usbserial
usbserinfo:1.0 driver:2.0
1: module:qcserial name:"Qualcomm USB modem" vendor:1199 product:68c0 num_ports:1 port:0 path:usb-AmbUSB-1
2: module:qcserial name:"Qualcomm USB modem" vendor:1199 product:68c0 num_ports:1 port:0 path:usb-AmbUSB-1
3: module:qcserial name:"Qualcomm USB modem" vendor:1199 product:68c0 num_ports:1 port:0 path:usb-AmbUSB-1
```

Comment: The `/dev/ttyUSBx` numbers are assigned by the kernel, and there are no guarantees whatsoever about these. Could you use symlinks via udev, e.g. as describe [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91629/symlinks-on-dev-ttyusb-via-udev) (first google result, there's probably plenty more Q&A for those...)?

Comment: System doesn't have udev.

Comment: Hm. Can you reliably trap when you need to deal with this situation, for example because you are sending the AT+RESET yourself? Is `/sys` populated, and does it contain info with which port the ttyUSBx are associated, potentially by following the symlink to the USB device? (Normally `udevadm` would show this information from `/sys`).

Comment: Unfortunately no - the module can restart itself when, for example, it loads a new internal firmware for a different SIM card. `/sys` is populated but I think the simplest solution will be to parse `/proc/tty/driver/usbserial`